# How to get a simple app deployed on watchOS 3 with Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, apple-watch

I can't get a simple app to run on watchOS 3 and it's driving me CRAZY!
I'm running with Xcode 8.

Recreate scenario: Create a newiOS app (defaults to deployment target 10), add WatchOS project (3.0). Try to compile.

I get:
Could not AOT the assembly (MT3001)

Changing Build link to "Don't Link" on all three projects and downgrading to target 8.4 and Watch OS 2.2 results:
Error MT1006: Could not install the application on the device: Sent message error( error : 0xe800002d).

3. Changing to target 10, but keeping Watch OS 2 finally gets compiled and installed on the phone and deployed on device, but debugger either:
   A. Never manage to connect over Wifi to the watch (stuck at "waiting for the app to connect on port 10000)
   B.  Get the following error:

Launched watch application 'com.XXX.testwatch.watchkitapp' on 'Apple Watch' with pid 270
Exception: Xamarin.Hosting.MobileDeviceException: Send Message Error (error: 0xe800002d)
  at Xamarin.Hosting.RealDevice.StartSession () <0x118c24dd0 + 0x0009d> in :0 
  at Xamarin.Hosting.DebugService+c__AnonStorey6.<>m__0 (System.Object v) <0x118c24450 + 0x000cf> in :0 
[MVID] 703d5be3b466420882f6cb97c41b6723 0,1

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I am having similar issues, I found that it is almost impossible to debug on the watch. I have never got it to connect. One thing I have been doing is waiting till I see the "waiting for the app to connect on port 10000" then force killing the app by Holding the Side button till the power off screen appears then Holding the digital crown button. Then restarting the app. if that fails to pick up my changes I have been restarting the watch. This is just to pick up the changes I have made between deployments, as it seems to just crash after deploying again. Very Annoying

Answer (score 2):

I've submitted a bug report To Xamarin. They confirmed. You need to modify the default compilation to disable the incremental build.